# how to deny login access for incorrect login in iOS swift

Tags: swift, authentication

I want to deny access for either an incorrect userEmail or userPassword but am not sure how to add in both details. and my code to deny login for an incorrect email is not having any effect, or returning any errors.  It just lets everyone log in. How can I correct this code?

```
func displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage:String)
{

    var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Alert", message:userMessage, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

  let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler:nil);
    myAlert.addAction(okAction);

  self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);

}


@IBAction func loginButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let userEmail = userEmailTextField.text;
    let userPassword = userPasswordTextField.text;

    let userEmailStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail");

    let userPasswordStored = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userPassword");

    if(userEmailStored == userEmail)
    {
        if(userPasswordStored == userPassword)
        {
            // Login is successfull
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);
        }
        //Check if passwords match
        else if(userPasswordStored != userPassword)

        {
        //    Display an alert message
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");

            displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match");
            return;

        }
    }
```

Comment: In this code you don't have any way of logging in, where is the code that tells you that someone is logged in?

Comment: it is a login button, the fields are user text fields on the storyboard. On another page is the register form which has stored username and user passwords. So this page is checking, on the press of the login button, if their access is approved or denied.

Comment: the login lines, which work,are: if(userEmailStored == userEmail)
    {
        if(userPasswordStored == userPassword)
        {
            // Login is successfull
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn");
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize();

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil);

Comment: yea login button only prints "Passwords do not match" when you have correct email and incorrect password, this code is not doing anything else, how do you know that user is logged in? maybe he pass wrong email. and nothing happens

Comment: yes that is my question that this post is about. The login works. The question is how to deny access if h/she has the wrong password.

Comment: you have nothing to deny, if password is not correct you have nothing. What do you want? crash app? code is correct

Comment: If you mean "how do you know that the user is logged in" means how do you know its the correct username, its the line checking if its the username stored. The code here does the check. else if(userPasswordStored != userPassword) My post is asking for help please on how to code it to be denied. I added NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false,forKey:"isUserLoggedIn"); but that is not enough to deny access.

Comment: if password is not correct I want to deny access with a message "wrong username/password. Please retry".

Comment: Eg I have the alert message line already coded in " displayMyAlertMessage("Passwords do not match"). That is the result I want. For it to be denied instead of logging in, and for that message to arise. I want to also add the code to check the username and do the same if the username does not match the username stored.

Comment: if you go step by step with breakpoints, what is the result? you are missing } else { for if(userPasswordStored == userPassword) you need that message too and then you will have displayed message if someone provide wrong password, and all you say is that you want only that message

Comment: In your code there is nothing that deny or approve access. That confuses me a lot when you say that something is not working and user is always logged in

Comment: ok this question confuses you. Can someone else please answer this then pls that it not confused, can solve this? The point of logging in, the whole purpose of the code is clear- to only log in someone who's username and password equals the details that were given in user registration. That is the problem to solve. To confirm one more time, in my code there is nothing that denies access, it just gives a message. That is the point - I want the code to deny access. Not just give a message. Yes this code logs in the user. My problem is that I want it to *not* log in the user. Thanks. Anyone else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're first checking whether the email is correct, and then if it is you're checking the password inside that block. You haven't provided any code to run if the email is incorrect.

Instead of structuring it like this:

```
if userEmailStored == userEmail {
    if userPasswordStored == userPassword {
        // Login successful
    } else {
        // Login unsuccessful
    }
}
```

Try structuring it like this:

```
if userEmailStored == userEmail && userPasswordStored == userPassword {
    // Login successful
} else if userEmailStored != userEmail {
    // Login unsuccessful (email incorrect)
} else /* if userPasswordStored != userPassword */ {
    // Login unsuccessful (password incorrect)
}
```

Note: on line 5, I've commented out the condition `if userPasswordStored != userPassword` because it's not actually required.

However, you may notice that when you log into most websites, if you get your details wrong, they don't specify whether it was your username or email that was incorrect.

For example:

[image: Stackoverflow incorrect credentials message]

They do it that way because it's more secure. So you may want to consider simply doing it like this:

```
if userEmailStored == userEmail && userPasswordStored == userPassword {
    // Login successful
} else {
    // Login unsuccessful
}
```

---

**Important note:**

Remember that NSUserDefaults isn't in any way encrypted, so if you're ever planning on storing a username and a password in there... don't. It's stored as XML (I believe), so anyone can simply go and look at it with minimal effort. Use Keychain instead!

---

A less important note: There's one place where you have two whole lines of whitespace between your `else if` and its bracket, and some other messy things in the rest of your code. You'll probably get more people answering your questions, as well as making it a lot easier for you and other people to understand your code, if you put in some effort to make it more readable. Two lines of whitespace before an opening bracket is an eyesore, and lots of that can make code really difficult to understand.

Comment: very help! Thank you so much Soren, will try that now. And thank you for the tips and very helpful explanation about the code and about making the code more readable. I'm a beginner learner (so having more white space made it easier for me to read, and I had planned to add in notes in there)- I will edit that now to make it more readable. Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome! I hope you can sort out the problem. Whitespace is helpful, but try to put it in places that make logical sense. You could always take a look at a style guide, like the [Github Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide), although some of the things in there are a bit unnecessary for a beginner. You could also take a look at some code to try to get a feel for the way people lay out their code ([shameless self plug](https://github.com/sorenmortensen/Symonds-API)). Best of luck to you, and I'm sure with experience your code will grow to be beautiful :)